# OEMBED seems to have stopped working

Tags: oembed

I had upgraded from 3.0 to 3.1 and oembed worked normally. All of a sudden I've lost embedding when directly pasting video url into the editor. My embed setting is selected under "media". Any ideas what could be going on?

I've changed themes, ultimately to the native 2010 and still no function. I've tried turning the embed setting on and off in the admin as well to no avail.

Comment: have you tried using the embed shortcodes to see if that helps?  Also, any plugins active?

Comment: No new plugins. Embed code does not work either.

Comment: Even though there are no new plugins, maybe still try to disable plugins?

Comment: Yea - no love on that. No idea - Guess I'll have to try and reinstall my installation of WP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears I've been hoodwinked by my local setup & accidentally stopping connections to vimeo / youtube. This resulted in the video url appearing as only text. Once my setup was restarted everything appears to be working properly. Sorry for the confabulation.